# amazon rds logs all queries

Tags: mysql-5.6, amazon-rds, performance, slow-log

I have enabled slow query log on Amazon RDS with following configuration.

```
long_query_time = 0.5
general_log     = 0
log_output      = TABLE
min_examined_row_limit = 1000
slow_query_log = 1
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1
```

to read slow query log , I am using following command from mysql workbench.

```
select * from mysql.slow_log where db = 'my_database' order by start_time desc;
```

but when I have seen log table, it shows me lots of queries used by mysql itself. like it shows me "performance_schema" related queries too. I want to filter it with my query only. does It has any option for this?